# nullable: false in Grails Domain Class constraints

Tags: grails

I am having code

```
static constraints = {
    stringValiable1(nullable: false)
    stringValiable2(nullable: false)
    stringValiable3(nullable: false)
}
```

Is there a method where I can abstract out the `(nullable: false)` so that I avoid using it again and again. Also can it be done at package level so that I can use it throughout the other classes as well.

Comment: Domain class properties are `nullable: false` by default. So above constraints can be removed as long as `@Validateable(nullable: true)` AST or `Validateable` trait (only in Grails 3) with default nullable true is not used.

Comment: I am following standards where the property has to be set expllicitly. So according to your statement I would need two Strings(or whatever data type): one for `nullable: false` and `nullable: true`

Comment: Which standard? If that is so, then you are contradicting yourself because your actual question is to abstract out `nullable: false` but now (as per "The-Standard") you want `nullable: false` to be set explicitly per property.

Comment: Codenarc ... The rule DuplicateMapLiteral does not allow occurrence of `nullable: false` more than once . SO I am forced to have it declared in an variable(I don't know of what type).     There were also DuplicateNumberLiteral , DuplicateStringLiteral for which I just declared the values in the variables of the given type. But I'm not able to figure the same for DuplicateMapLiteral

Comment: What I was trying to convey is that the constraint `stringValiable1(nullable: false)` is not required at all because the constraint will be applied to `stringValiable1` by default. You can remove those lines. As far as Codenarc is concerned, I think the rules can be tweaked to fit the need.

Comment: I would definitely get rid of that Codenarc rule or at least modify it to ignore the constraints block. You are going to end up using other constraints more than once as well, like `blank: false`.

Comment: I think thsi is what I will do `boolean isNullable = false    static constraints = {
    stringValiable1(nullable: isNullable)
    stringValiable2(nullable: isNullable)
    stringValiable3(nullable: isNullable)
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to factor out is simply a `Map`. For example, the method call `stringValiable1(nullable: false)` is syntatic sugar for `stringValiable1([nullable: false])`.

So, factoring it out is a matter of putting a `Map` in some class, and then using it:

### Place to store Map

```
package foo.bar

class MyConstraints {
    static nullable = [nullable: true]
    static blank = [blank: true]
}
```

### The domain class

```
static import foo.bar.MyConstraints.*

class SomeDomainClass {
    ...
    static constraints = {
        stringVariable1(nullable)
        stringVariable2(nullable + blank)
    }
}
```